# Editing ini files with ruby, clean way preferred

Tags: ruby, ini

Hello I'm interested in editing an ini file using ruby. By that I mean that I want to read e.g. a variable in the file, change its contents and save the changes back to the file. I would also like to perform the edits in a clean ruby-ish manner. There is [this relative gem](https://github.com/TwP/inifile) but as far as I understand its functions I can't open a file, edit its contents and save back to disk. I can either read an existing file or create a new one. It can possibly be done with its merge fucntion? I'm not sure how though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say:

> as I understand its functions I can't open a file, edit its contents and save back to disk.

You can do this fairly easily:

```
require 'inifile'

# Open and read the file
ini = IniFile.load('my_file.ini')

# Read its current contents
puts ini['section1']['foo']

# Edit the contents
ini['section1']['foo'] = 'baz'

# Save it back to disk
# You don't need to provide the filename, it remembers the original name
ini.save
```

Comment: Oh so it reads the entire file in memory and when I change a variable all the others remain intact? So when I save it writes all the contents at once?

Comment: Hmmmm what if the file doesn't have sections? This is my file
http://pastebin.com/4c4WRGkC

Comment: @Crone ["If the INI file lacks any section declarations, or if there are properties decalared before the first section, then these properties will be placed into a default "global" section. The name of this section can be configured when creating an IniFile instance."](https://github.com/TwP/inifile#global-properties)

Comment: @Crone unfortunately this will remove all your comments though.

Comment: Thanks got it. I'm new to ruby and gems, I could find the answer alone it seems.

Comment: @Crone be careful with this – I’ve just tried it with your file and it doesn’t seem to parse some sections correctly. Check the docs for the syntax it uses, you may need to use quotes in your file, or even find a different way of parsing it.

Comment: Yea I just came to write that, regex are enclosed in [] so after a certain point the value of the regex becomes the section

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49701/discussion-between-crone-and-matt)